# Is my graphic card damaged?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

yesterday I installed the new tomb raider, every 2 minutes or so it froze for 10 seconds.

So after 1h I quit the game and when I tried to **browse the internet chrome was making my screen go black (and it still do) every 20 seconds** then I would get a message saying :

(translation from french) :
The display driver NVDIA windows kernel mode driver, 314.07 is not responding.

So I uninstalled the current display driver (note that it froze and rebooted my computer during the uninstallation, I actually had to do it 2 times) 
Then I installed the newest version : 314.07 and rebooted.

But the problem is still there :/

I read somewhere that this was a hardware issue, is there a way to test it?

I'm running windows 7 64Bits,
graphic card is a GTX 680

Comment: If tomb raider installed the newest driver for you (314.07) I'd try an older version.

Comment: Is the CPU fan spinning? Is the power supply fan spinning? Is the graphics card fan spinning? Is the CPU temperature normal? Is the GPU temperature normal?

Comment: No I installed tomb raider with an old driver, then I installed the new driver, no change.

Yeah everything is spinning and good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i've went into safe mode, uninstalled everything,
cleaned my registery with ccleaner afterwards and it went away.

But tomb raider is still crashing (with the same message) after 5-6 minutes of game time.
Apparently this is normal as nVidia released :

“We are aware of major performance and stability issues with GeForce GPUs running Tomb Raider with maximum settings. Unfortunately, NVIDIA didn’t receive final code until this past weekend which substantially decreased stability, image quality and performance over a build we were previously provided. We are working closely with Crystal Dynamics to address and resolve all game issues as quickly as possible.
In the meantime, we would like to apologize to GeForce users that are not able to have a great experience playing Tomb Raider, as they have come to expect with all of their favorite PC games.”

You just can't play it with every parameter maxed out even if you GPU is powerfull enought

Until a fix is released, workarounds are possible. Simply disable V-Sync and Tessellation in the game's graphics settings. Players running the game on an SLI set up should use the nVidia inspector tool

Comment: Know that if your game crashes you will have to uninstall and reinstall the nVidia driver, otherwhise you won't be able to use an internet browser for more than 5 minutes :/

Answer (score 0):

Could be an hardware issue. You could try to create and boot from a Linux Live-CD (like http://www.knoppix.org/) and see if it also crashes there. This is probably fast then restore Windows.

Anyway... I doubt it that it is a hardware problem if Windows itself is running stable.

Comment: Let's hope so, I'll try tonight, no access to my computer right now